# jquery Datepicker does not close when clicking on it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using jquery datepicker widget all over my application always initializing it with the same method, the simplest one

```
$("[ID$=dueDate]").datepicker();
```

I have checked the documentation and there is nothing that seems to help on it. How can I have the datepicker to close when I click on a day?

Comment: More likely than not there is a bug somewhere else that is stopping the script. Are you running firebug? (if not get fire fox and firebug) If the console is active it will tell you if there are any errors. I doubt anyone here could help you, since it is probably something very specific to your code.

Comment: Off topic, but you can speed up your selector by adding the tag name, so jQuery doesn't need to test *every* element on the page for the ID attribute (in browsers that don't have `querySelectorAll` anyway). `$("input[ID$=dueDate]")`

Comment: y arent you calling it like 

    $("#dueDate").datepicker();

Comment: @dustynachos: I am using chrome developer tool and dont see any error before and after clicking on a date. I am also using the timepicker addon available here: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/. Can this be the cause?

Comment: @patrick_dw: thanks a lot!!! off topic per off topic.... how did you format the code as dimmed in stackoverflow comments? :)

Comment: @Ascherer: yes in some part I call it using your way. It does'nt make difference on the question anyway.... just picked up a sample with ID$...

Comment: @Lorenzo - [Here's a link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/text-formatting-now-allowed-in-comments-list-of-proven-and-disproven-abilities) to some formatting options for comments. For code formatting like that, you use the [grave accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) character, probably above your left TAB key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I was using the jQuery timepicker addon available [here](http://trentrichardson.com).
It caused the problem with the version I was using.

The latest version does not conflict anymore.